# RVM for multi-user

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I installed RVM with [this official tutorial](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/), but when I log in to console again I must run `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` again for all users. All users are in RVM group. Anybody help me? I have Ubuntu 12.04, but I had same problems with Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your settings for gnome-terminal, I will be adding an additional check for it in RVM installer:

https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

Comment: thank you, I add code from /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh to end of ~/.bashrc

Comment: @quatermain i think you missed the point, please read https://rvm.io/support/faq/#shell_login ... using .bashrc for sourcing RVM might be dangerous - and should not be done, but of course it's your choice.

Comment: I use .bashrc only when capistrano login with ssh. I don't use ssh, only capistrano, is it dangerous too? Passenger use rvm's lib and it's  working without my "stupid fix" what I did before.

Comment: it's exactly the point where it can hit you, rvm could in case of problems do some output during loading. this means any `scp` transfers (capistrano `download`/`upload`) will fail in this case. Any problems you will get with it will be really hard to investigate - you can detect them only knowing the details.

Comment: Thank you, I installed RVM because I think I will use two Ruby version, but I transfered my projects to 1.9.3. I have 2 old projects in REE so I will install new Virtual Machine for them. I'm not good in english so I understand not very good your link. Thank you for your time.